# How to pass a secureObject in a release definition variable?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, secureobject

In the release definition variables, you can define a string and make it a secureString by marking it secret via the padlock and then using convert-tosecurestring in the script arguments.

But what is the syntax for defining an object and a secureObject? There doesn't appear to be a mention in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object or secureObject is not supported in VSTS build/release variable.

You can uses secure variable directly in build/release task (the variable will be decrypted), so you just need to convent to the object per to your requirement in the build/release task (e.g. PowerShell).

A simple sample to store a JSON string to secure variable, then convert it to JSON object and modify.

1. Add secure variable in build definition (obj: `'{"name": "mynodeDefinition"}'`)
2. Add PowerShell task to build definition (Arguments: -pass $(obj);

Script:

```
param(
[string]$pass)
$bodyContent=$pass| ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $bodyContent
$bodyContent.Name="NewValue"
Write-Host $bodyContent
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, good to know it's not supported, it'll save me pulling my hair out trying various combinations. JSON seems like a reasonable work around. Should `[string]$pass` be `[securestring]$pass` ?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith Using [string]$pass.